# Rails - Mention the gem/plugin to implement inbox feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, message, inbox

In rails 3 (or above), I want to implement a messaging system, which gem or plugin I can use for it? Please help me to implement a inbox feature with all actions in my rails project.

https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages is this gem will suits for all inbox actions in rails 4.1 ?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would suggest you mailboxer gem,

https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer

By this, you can get messaging system and inbox features like real time mailing system.

Comment: Thank You. But here I am not getting Star & Unstar message feature.